# Is WHERE field IS NULL quicker than >0

Tags: sql, sql-server, null

I have a number of Integer ID fields (SQL Server) that we are filtering on. I'm prepping to do an Insert of new rows. Is it quicker to use `WHERE fieldname IS NOT NULL` or could I use `WHERE fieldId > 0` to get a list of existing Id values?

Comment: check out in QUERY EXECUTION PLAN

Comment: Why would you use either?  How are they even comparable?

Comment: `NOT NULL` and `>0` are 2 VERY different things.  0 is not null.  You're comparing 2 things that aren't alike.

Comment: your question is not clear. what do you need your IDs for?

Comment: @KrisGruttemeyer . . . I think the point is that the values are always non-negative.  Probably counts of some sort or foreign key references.

Comment: @GordonLinoff you're very right.  Unfortunately, as it stand now, we don't quite have enough info on this one from the OP.

Comment: If there were a performance difference, it would be negligible.  Both `where` clauses can take advantage of indexes.  My guess is that any efficiency at the low-level binary stage would be masked by the time taken to compile the query.  But, you can always test on your data on your system.

Comment: Tks Gordon. I was not sure if there was some low level optimisation that would allow a comparison to zero be faster than NULL, but as you say, the availability of an Index will be much more important/significant.
Kris, I am aware that they are different things, but in this case they are functionally equivalent, hence the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server (as with any database) has a rather complex design of the data page. [Here](http://improve.dk/deciphering-a-sql-server-data-page/) is a reference to more detail.

The idea, though, is that NULL flags are stored in a bitmap separate from the actual values. In order to read a value from the data page, the storage engine has to parse the NULL flag, regardless of what else it does. The value makes no sense without the NULL flag.

From this perspective, any comparison to a value requires both parsing the NULL flag and the retrieving the value. It is (theoretically) possible that the engine could only fetch the NULL flag if the value is not needed.

Your question is really: "Does SQL Server optimize `IS NULL` comparisons to only fetch the `NULL` flag from the bitmap and not the rest of the value?" I do not know the answer to this question.

However, for on-page data values, the difference between copying or not copying the extra four bytes would be really, really, really small.  There are more important differences with off-page storage, so those *might* be optimized.

My best guess, based on my knowledge of the storage architecture, is that `NULL` value comparisons *could* have a very, very, very small optimization. I don't know if there really is a difference. In any case, the extra cycle or two of savings would probably not be noticeable.